# Several attach field on a form

Tags: form, attachments

I have a quite big HTML form (no infopath) and I need to add **at least 2 attachment button/field** on the same. Unfortunately I realized that i cannot because the "Attach" button works on the ID of the (first) attachment field which cannot be just duplicated.
Does anybody has a workaround in order to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own file control in HTML and use below script.

```
//Enable Multiple Upload Script

$('.attachmentButton').change(function(event){  
//alert("change");  
//startUpload(self, function (){ reloadPage(); }, event);   
$("#WSOutput").html("<b>Please wait while files are getting attached. </b>");
 var listName = claimHeaderList; // change these to suit your list and item
 selectedFilesLength = event.target.files.length;
            asyncLoop({
    length : event.target.files.length+1,
    functionToLoop : function(loop, i){
        setTimeout(function(){
            //document.write('Iteration ' + i + ' <br>');

            handleFileChange(listName,itemId,event.target.files[i],i);
            loop();
        },10);
    },
    callback : function(){
    location.reload();
    //document.write('All done!');
    }    
});

});   


 });

 var asyncLoop = function(o){
    var i=-1;

    var loop = function(){
        i++;
        if(i==o.length){o.callback(); return;}
        o.functionToLoop(loop, i);
    } 
    loop();//init
}

 function handleFileChange(listName,itemId,file,length,_callback){
 //alert(length+"selectedFilesLength:" + selectedFilesLength );
 if( !(length==selectedFilesLength))
 {

 //alert(file.name);
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
 var getFileBuffer = function(file) {

  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
  }

  reader.onerror = function(e) {
    deferred.reject(e.target.error);
  }

  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

  return deferred.promise();
};
   getFileBuffer(file).then(function(buffer) {
  var binary = "";
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  var i = bytes.byteLength;
  while (i--) {
    binary = String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]) + binary;
  }
  $("#WSOutput").html("<b>Please wait while files are getting attached. </b>").SPServices({
    operation: "AddAttachment",
    async: false,
    listName: listName,
    listItemID: itemId,
    fileName: file.name,
    attachment: btoa(binary),
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        //$("#WSOutput").html("");
                }
  });
}); 
//_callback(); 
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" class="attachmentButton" name="attachmentButton"/>
<div id="WSOutput"> &#160;</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I found more convenient to "move" the attach input form using child properties.

Comment: @Marpio Can You addd more details how You did it?..